# How to put a TextField With multiple selection and visible text as Tags

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I really need somebody help. I know the question its crazy, but I trying to have a text field with a tableView as inputView, for what? Because a picker let you select just an option, and I need to have multiple selection, something like [this](https://github.com/chenzeyu/CZPicker)

Them when I have selected I want to see the selection like tags, just like the image below

[image]

The thing is I dont know how to do it at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't use a textfield because they simply don't allow you to make tags like that. You could instead use `UILabel`, and then put each word inside of a different label. It is also probably a good idea to make a label subclass which looks like the tags.

Comment: @Eric I will try to do that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a UITableView, use a **UICollectionView** because it doesn't look like you need the full functionality of a UITableView.

Don't use a*UITextField, unless you're trying to get user input. Instead use a **UILabel** to simply display text. As for assigning text to each cell, store all the strings into an array and assign each string to the cell index accordingly.

```
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["A", "Tag", "One", "More", "Tag"]
```

In the **cellForRowAt** function, declare this:

```
cell.labelName.text = arrayOfStrings[indexPath.row]
```

This assigns each string to each cell respectively.

Hopefully this helps you out! I'm a fairly new developer as well :)

Comment: Thanks! I know want you mean, I will try to do it, if everything goes on I will let you know!